# Store T-SQL warning messages into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way I can insert the warning messages into a table?
Specifically I mean the warnings that are like 'The module 'x' depends on the missing object 'y'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.' which are not picked up by the system error messages

Comment: I've recently implemented something along the lines of https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpSqlEventLog, Things get interesting when errors occur inside a transaction.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to know about *every* single message, as some of them are completely benign, for example `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation`.

You can use [`sp_altermessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-altermessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to log specific errors that are not logged by default.

```
EXEC sp_altermessage
  @message_id = 2007,
  @parameter = 'WITH_LOG',
  @parameter_value = 'false';
```

The last parameter specifies whether to log to the Windows event log also.

The error you are talking about is error 2007. You can view all errors using

```sql
select * from sys.messages
```

---

Another option is to set up an [Extended Events session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver16), which logs all errors.

For example, I have this one on my server (note that it only logs to the ring buffer, but you can log to a file also).

```sql
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Errors] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported (
    ACTION (
      sqlserver.client_hostname,
      sqlserver.sql_text,
      sqlserver.tsql_stack
    )
    WHERE ([severity] > 10 AND [error_number] <> 3980 AND [error_number] <> 17830)
)
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer (
    SET max_events_limit = 50,
        occurrence_number= 50
)
WITH (
  MAX_MEMORY = 4096 KB,
  EVENT_RETENTION_MODE = ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
  MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY = 30 SECONDS,
  MAX_EVENT_SIZE = 0 KB,
  MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE = NONE,
  TRACK_CAUSALITY = OFF,
  STARTUP_STATE=ON
);

GO
```